# Is there a way to share Google Calendars between two different organizations?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace

Suppose that I have two companies, they use different Google tenants. Is there a way to allow Google Calendar sharing between these two organizations?

I want employees in Company A to see Company B's employees' calendars without any specific sharing operations for each employee.

What can the admin do to achieve this kind of sharing?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to share a Calendar between two organizations, without configuring per-user sharing options, is to publish it publicly, you can learn how [here](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37083#zippy=%2Cmark-your-calendar-as-public). Then you would only need to [share the Calendar link](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37083#zippy=%2Cshare-as-a-link) between those two organizations. Please remember that the admin of those organizations should [allow external sharing](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60765#zippy=%2Callow-or-restrict-external-sharing).

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution, but you can compose a team of individual calendars via [Orglio](https://orglio.com)